# InputMismatchException when reading numbers and text using Scanner

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, inputmismatchexception

I would like to have the user input a line of text as long as `x` is not equal to the value of `numOfContestans`. When I run the code, I get an `InputMismatchException`. Does anyone have an idea on how to solve this error?

```
try {
    int numOfContestants = scan.nextInt();
    int problems = scan.nextInt();
    scan.nextLine();
    int x = 0;

    while (x != numOfContestants) {
        String input = scan.nextLine();
        x++;
    }
    System.out.println(problems);
} catch(InputMismatchException e) {
    System.out.println("Something went wrong");
}
```

Comment: Most of the time, Scanner requires that you check before reading.  You have to check that the Scanner `has` the thing in question.  Try `hasNextLine()` before reading.

Comment: What is the input sequence for which yo are getting the exception?

Comment: @YoungHobbit I am able to enter two digits then one line of text before the error occurs.

Comment: You should avoid "silently" adding code to the question after an answer was provided. You can add code, but also explain in the question that you edited the code corresponding to the provided answer, but it doesn't solve your problem.

Comment: Also please provide the input you're using.

Answer (score 1):

You do not list the input that causes a problem. If you try this input,

```
3
2
line1
line2
line3
```

nextInt does not read the CR/LF at the end of the line. The first call to nextLine is empty. The loop runs the correct amount of times, but the first pass does not read a complete line. After reading the problems, read the next line.

```
int problems = scan.nextInt();        
String input = scan.nextLine();
```

You could also enter you data so it looks like

```
3
2 line1
line2
line3
```

Then your code works.

I could not generate an error, as long as the intergers were entered properly.

I do not know how nextLine could cause a TypeMismatchException. I have run this code and can only cause such an error if an integer is entered incorrectly. Please provide the input that causes the error.

Comment: Thank you. I am somewhat confuse on how I should alter the code? Are you suggesting I take String input = scan.nextLine() out of the while loop? May you clarify please? Thanks.

Comment: Leave your code as it is and add an extra scan after you read the int. I moved the definition of String input to its new, first use.

Comment: So once I move input out of the while loop, what remains in the loop? @downeyt

Comment: LEAVE YOUR CODE AS IT IS, but add an additional nextLine after the last nextInt. Since you do not need this value, you could just call nextLine without saving the result.

Comment: I edited the initial code post above. That does not work either. Thanks for the help. @downeyt

Comment: You need to do something with the input. Currently, the code is not using it. Add a System.out.println(input) inside the loop to see that it works. If you need all the values later, you might put them in a List. 'problems' does not contain all the lines that were just read, it is just the count that was read earlier.

Comment: Even though it is correct that the first `nextLine` returns an empty String, it is not clear how this causes OPs problem, when OP correctly enters two numbers (which we can only assume).